# Both two Prisma schema have foreign key of each other's ID

Tags: prisma

```
    model Users {
  id               Int                @id @default(autoincrement())
  business_id      Int?               @db.Int
  Businesses       Businesses?        @relation(fields: [business_id], references: [id], onUpdate: Cascade, onDelete: Cascade)
  name             String             @db.VarChar(255)
  surname          String             @db.VarChar(255)
  email            String             @unique(map: "email") @db.VarChar(255)
  password         String             @db.VarChar(255)
}


model Businesses {
  id          Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  name        String     @db.VarChar(255)
  owner_id    Int        @db.Int
  Users       Users      @relation(fields: [owner_id], references: [id], onUpdate: Cascade, onDelete: Cascade)
  phone       String     @db.VarChar(255)
}
```

So the logic is like this that in the Model User the value of business id is opsional and in the Business's model the owner_id the ID is mandatory.

In the User's table I am getting this error:

```
Error parsing attribute "@relation": The relation fields `Users` on Model `Businesses` and `Businesses` on Model `Users` both provide the `fields` argument in the @relation attribute. You have to provide it only on one of the two fields.
```

And in the Business's model this error:

```
Error parsing attribute "@relation": The relation fields `Users` on Model `Businesses` and `Businesses` on Model `Users` both provide the `references` argument in the @relation attribute. You have to provide it only on one of the two fields.
```

1. Relationship Between **User -> Business**: many to one ( many users can be part of one business)
2. Relationship Between **Business -> User** : one to one (only one user can be the owner of one business)

Comment: What kind of relationship exists between Users and Businesses? Is it a 1-1, 1-many, or many to many? That'll help in coming up with the best answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

Given the assumptions/relationships in your question

- One business can have many users, each user can belong to only one business (one to many relationship, called "business2user" in the schema below)
- One user can own one business, a business is owned by one user. (one to one relationship, called "business2owner" in the schema below)

a `prisma.schema` could look like this:

```
model User {
    id          Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
    business_id Int?      @db.Int
    business    Business? @relation(fields: [business_id], references: [id], name: "business2user", onUpdate: Cascade, onDelete: Cascade)
    name        String    @db.VarChar(255)
    surname     String    @db.VarChar(255)
    email       String    @unique(map: "email") @db.VarChar(255)
    password    String    @db.VarChar(255)
    ownedBusiness  Business? @relation(name: "business2owner")
}

model Business {
    id       Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
    name     String @db.VarChar(255)
    owner_id Int    @unique @db.Int
    owner    User   @relation(fields: [owner_id], references: [id], name: "business2owner", onUpdate: Cascade, onDelete: Cascade)
    users    User[] @relation(name: "business2user")
    phone    String @db.VarChar(255)
}
```

I took the liberty to rename `Users` to `User` and `Businesses` to `Business` to improve interpretability.